# Click toggle works on Chrome and Safari but not Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox

```
$(function() {
  $(".trigger").on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".target").toggle();
  });
  $(".individual-project").on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".individual-project-toggle").toggle();
  });
})
```

Hello everyone. I have a list of divs that toggle between expand and collapse on click. This works fine on Chrome and Safari but I can't seem to be able to click on Firefox.
Console show the error:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

Does anyone know why/how to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: What console output do you get in Firefox?

Comment: ReferenceError: event is not defined

Comment: HTML is also helpful to reproduce problem.

Comment: @mk123 have you searched for this error? There are a lot of similar questions. Anyway, your callback functions do not define `event`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you didn't pass the event for the event.preventDefault()

```
$(function() {
  $(".trigger").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".target").toggle();
  });
  $(".individual-project").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".individual-project-toggle").toggle();
  });
})
```

Firefox doesn't have a "built in" handler for the event.
Cheers!